# C++ Instantiate class from static function

Tags: c++, static, instantiation, delete-operator

I'm trying to instantiate an object from a static member function. I've defined:

```
class A
{
public:
    A( );
    A(int aParam);
    ~A( );
    static A* Creator( );
private:
    int m_nData;
};
```

And Implemented:

```
#include "A.h"

A::A()
{
}

A::A(int aParam)
{
    m_nData = aParam;
}

A::~A()
{
}

A* A::Creator()
{
    return new A(0);
}
```

It works ok, but have problem when deleting object:

```
#include "A.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    A* pointer = A::Creator();

    delete pointer;
    return 0;
}
```

This example works as expected. I'm affraid the problem could be more complex. I'll try to give more details:
I've a class similar to described here inside a dll library (Windows). When I call static function from my program, I get an error (when debugging): 
HEAP[program.exe]: Invalid address specified to RtlValidateHeap( 0000000000BA0000, 000000000264B3D0 )
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in program.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in program.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

As I've tested, it seems that the newly created object it's being allocated in the stack.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: this doesn't even compile, please post a compilable solution.

Comment: The only thing wrong with the code you've posted is the lack of destructor definition and a couple syntax errors.  This would cause a linker error except under the most extreme situations.  Something you've not shown is the culprit of your crash.

Comment: I expect something else is wrong.  The object is definitely allocated on the heap and the minimal example you've shown should work fine.  Does that exact example fail somehow or did you miss an important detail in simplifying it for posting?

Comment: -1 not actual code (at the time of this comment).

Comment: Please post a **complete, minimal, self-containing** example that exhibits your problem.

Comment: This is well-known design pattern on Symbian or any environment with very small stack. After fixing obvious errors, your code works as expected, see for yourself: http://codepad.org/54Q3TYSN

Comment: Ok, sorry I just pasted significant code. I just wanted to know if it is something wrong with this code. I'll try to edit and make it compilable.

Comment: It sounds from the description that you allocate from the DLL and then free from the application. If the Creator() method is in a DLL then you would usually supply a method for freeing that memory from within the DLL.

Comment: Hi tinman, thanks a lot. I'll check that

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the destructor implementation. The compiler should warn you on that. With gcc and the previously mentioned fix, it works.